# Getting the Parameter name of a Value in a URL request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, urlparse

I have a Python App Engine web app class that I am accessing with the following POST url: `http://localhost:8087/moderate?5649364211118945661=on`

How can I get the **Parameter** name - not the **value** of the `5649364211118945661`parameter, but a list of all the parameter names that contain the `on` value.

For example, in the following url:

```
http://localhost:8087/moderate?5649364211118945661=on&23984729386481734=on&456287432349725=on&6753847523429875=off
```

how can I extract this:

```
['5649364211118945661', '23984729386481734', '456287432349725']
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use urlparse, http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html.

```
import urlparse
url = urlparse.urlparse('http://localhost:8087/moderate?5649364211118945661=on&23984729386481734=on&456287432349725=on&6753847523429875=off')
query = urlparse.parse_qs(url.query)
print [key for key, value in query.iteritems() if value == 'on']
```

If you are talking about an incoming URL on Google App Engine, use

```
args_on = [arg for arg in self.request.arguments() if self.request.get(arg) == 'on']
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much. That is very helpful and complete. Works great.